# Calculating probability using std::binomial_distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, statistics, probability

Is it possible to calculate the probability of obtaining n success in k trials using std::binomial_distribution? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really no.

`std::binomial_distribution` is more of an adapter for random number generation rather than being something that can provide a cumulative density function.

You can implement a cumulative density function in a few lines of code yourself or have a search for a good mathematics library. (Use a Pascal's triangle approach as opposed to calculating large factorial numbers).

Comment: I had problems with factorial overflows, i'm using a recursive way:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula

Is it a good idea?

Comment: @Bathsheba: I mean you could do it using `std::binomial_distribution` if you want to do it by random sampling / law of large numbers, instead of just computing it out explicitly. I assume that this is part of OP's homework to do it both ways or something.

Answer (score 0):

To implement such PMF, like [Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

```
PMF(p, n,k) = n!/(k!*(n-k)!) p^k (1-p)^(n-k)
```

Good trick is to compute logarithm of it and the exponentiate it

For `log` of the factorial you have to use log of gamma function

Along the lines (not tested!)

```
double logChoose(int n, int k) {
    return std::lgamma(double(n+1)) - std::lgamma(double(k+1)) - std::lgamma(double(n-k+1));
}

double PMFBinomial(double p, int n, int k) {
    double lgr = logChoose(n, k) + double(k)*std::log(p) + double(n-k)*std::log(1-p);
    return std::exp(lgr);
}
```